# Mac Terminal/ MySQL configuration issues | ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, mysql-error-2002

I've been getting this error when trying to navigate to MySQL in the command prompt. System Preferences shows it's running through port 3306. I'm new to programming and I'm just trying to keep up with tutorials, but a lot of this knowledge is stacked and without a properly working local database things just continue to get more and more confusing.

Also have been receiving this error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'hostname'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: To clarify, are you getting both errors? That would be most unusual. One says that the server is unreachable, and the other says that it is reachable but that you've not specified a password when a password is required. If you are experiencing these two errors on different machines, please delete one from the question and ask a separate question, in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: -@ ~ () $ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: when I type 'mysql' into the comman line I get hit with
'ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'

Comment: And in what circumstances do you get the other error?

Comment: Try specifying your host, that is, `mysql -u root -p -h127.0.0.1`

Comment: Looks like Mysql server has not started.
    
    mysqld stop
    mysql.server start

Had exactly the same issue, used the above command to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Mysql server has not started.

```
mysqld stop
mysql.server start
```

This will fix the issue.